# PHP : how to convert object to array using loop

Tags: php

(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Ford
            [models] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Fiesta
                    [1] => Focus
                    [2] => Mustang
                )

```
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => BMW
        [models] => Array
            (
                [0] => 320
                [1] => X3
                [2] => X5
            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Fiat
        [models] => Array
            (
                [0] => 500
                [1] => Panda
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: What do you want to do with it?  What you want has a huge impact as to how to parse it.  Are you asking about how to loop through every item?

Comment: Mean casting to array `(array) `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can use JSON functions to encode to JSON and then decode back to an array. This will not include private and protected members, however.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Alternatively, the following function will convert from an object to an array including private and protected members:

```
function objectToArray ($object) {
    if(!is_object($object) && !is_array($object))
        return $object;

    return array_map('objectToArray', (array) $object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to JSON-encode your object and then decode it back to an array:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), True);
```

Or if you prefer, you can traverse the object manually, too:

```
foreach ($object as $value) {
    $array[] = $value->name;
}
```

Try it!

Comment: Have you tried?